# What's the meaning of 道郡?

Tags: translation, meaning

I encountered this word '道郡' while reading a story set an China's ancient times. I tried Baidu and got some names such as  '怀道郡' and '狄道郡', so I think '道郡' may be an ancient counterpart to the modern word for 'county' (which is just 郡).

Can anyone give me an exact answer?

Comment: Fun fact, 道 is still used today in Korea and Japan as an administrative unit. 北海道 Hokkaidou is the only remaining 道 in Japan, and 道 is appended to each province in Korea.

Answer (score 3):

“道“ & “郡” were administrative division name.

in 秦 dynasty, the country is divided into 36 “郡“, each one is roughly the size of a province nowadays.

[image]

in 唐 dynasty, the country is divided into 15 “道“, each one is about the size of a province today.

[image]

county is an acceptable translation; however, i prefer “province”, or “state”.